# Qt on Linux embedded: Unable to get QBluetoothLocalDevice

Tags: c++, linux, qt, bluetooth, embedded-linux

I have a Linux embedded device using Linux kernel 3.17 and a WiLink 8 wireless module as Bluetooth device (uses UART) (see Gumstix AirStorm-y). Also, I have Qt 5.3.2 and Bluez 4.101 installed on it.

My problem is when I execute my Qt app, I can't get information on my bluetooth device using `QBluetoothLocalDevice`. For example, `QBluetoothLocalDevice::allDevices()` always returns an empty list and `QBluetoothLocalDevice::address()` always returns "00:00:00:00:00:00". If I try to execute the chat example, I get the `'Cannot bind chat server to "00:00:00:00:00:00"'` error.

I'm sure my bluetooth device is up and running:

```
hci0:  
Type: BR/EDR Bus: UART  
BD Address: 5C:31:3E:CE:C3:CE ACL MTU: 1021:6 SCO MTU: 180:4  
UP RUNNING PSCAN  
RX bytes:657 acl:0 sco:0 events:37 errors:0  
TX bytes:979 acl:0 sco:0 commands:37 errors:0
```

I can also do scan using hcitools.
Dbus is also running correctly, when I do `dbus-send --system --dest=org.bluez --print-reply / org.bluez.Manager.DefaultAdapter` I get:

```
method return sender=:1.5 -> dest=:1.12 reply_serial=2  
object path "/org/bluez/1743/hci0"
```

In my app, everything else seems to work just fine (I a have a QTCPserver and file manager with QFileSystemWatcher), it's only the BLuetooth part I can't manage to make it worked.